# "quatre fois l'an" or "quatre fois par an"

Tags: usage

> L'événement a lieu quatre fois ____.

Should "l'an" or "par an" go into the blank, or is it exactly the same either way? Is one more formal than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but "*deux fois l'an*" is pretty aged. You can hear it from grandparents or people living in the countryside.

Prefer "*Deux fois par an*", just know that the other one exists.

Answer (score 0):

> L'événement a lieu quatre fois l'an.

is equal to

> L'événement a lieu quatre fois par an.

in periodicity.

The first has a light negative overtone as something not very reliable or not very important while the second is just fact.